# Why can't I delete text entered into Firemonkey edit box under Android after pressing Enter/Return key?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, editbox

I type text into a Firemonkey edit box and press Enter/Return on the virtual keyboard. When I press Backspace, the entered text isn't deleted and the caret stays at the same position. The problem is resolved by changing the caret position by tapping inside the text, but not always.

If I programmatically delete the text in edit box after Enter/Return was pressed, there's another problem: the deleted text reappears in the edit box when I type new text into it.

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, but the problem appeared with earlier Delphi versions as well.

I assume that this might be Android's bug. My device is running Android 4.2.2.

Comment: It is Delphi bug, but I cannot find QP report at the moment.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for the info! So upgrading the OS won't help?

Comment: No. I have seen such issues on Android 6 and 7 with both Delphi Tokyo and Rio.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: i don't know. You can go search at [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com/) and find relevant bug reports. Usually known workarounds are mentioned in the reports.